# Can I use Lift's FieldSerializer to change a field on serialization?

Tags: json, scala, lift

I'm trying to html-escape all strings in my objects when serializing them with Lift's json library. I thought I could do this by passing an escape (partial) function to the objects' FieldSerializer, but this seems to *add* fields to the json-object - not *replace* them. You can see what I mean by running the following simple example and note that it outputs
`{"y":"test","x":"test"}` while I wanted `{"y":"test"}`:

```
import net.liftweb.json.Serialization
import net.liftweb.json.FieldSerializer
import net.liftweb.json.FieldSerializer._
import net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats
case class Simple(x: String)
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats + 
    FieldSerializer[Simple](renameTo("x","y"),renameFrom("y", "x"))
Serialization.write(Simple("test"))
```

Is there a way I can tell FieldSerializer to replace the field matched by my partial function?

Comment: You may want to ask on the lift mailing list at https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!forum/liftweb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try CoustomeSerializer:

```
  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats +
    new CustomSerializer[Simple](ser => ( {
      case JObject(JField("y", JString(x)) :: Nil) => Simple(x)
    }, {
      case simple: Simple => JObject(JField("y", JString(simple.x)) :: Nil)
    }))
```

*ps.I asked this on lift's google group,and got this answer,checkout https://groups.google.com/d/msg/liftweb/ShRrGNrsu6Y/sNw4JGdSU6sJ*

Comment: Thanks for asking on the mailing list for me - I never got around to follow up on this, as I found a workaround for my specific case :) Seems it's not possible to replace a field with FieldSerializer then. I really wanted to avoid writing a CustomSerializer, as, in the actual code, there are lots of other fields that are to be serialized the standard way.